# HttpStatus Ok(200) but I see a white page - Aspnet Mvc Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I'm developing the Asp.Net with RazorEngine. Project upload to server and run,
but giving statusCode 200(ok) and I see white page.

Note: I aslo tried two different servers.

Site Url : rest.gelecekten.net

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <!--<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />-->
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Restaurant;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MongoServer" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/Restaurant" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
    <compilation debug="true" optimizeCompilations="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <trace enabled="false" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="24.00:00:00" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>    
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
      <!--<remove name="OutputCache" />-->
      <remove name="AnonymousIdentification" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />      
    </modules>    
    <!--<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>-->
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Global.asax

```
protected void InitializeApplication()
    {
        //Initialize dependency injection
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
        Service.DependencyRegister.Register(containerBuilder);
        DependencyRegister.Register(containerBuilder);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        Engine.SetContainer(container);

        //View Engine Optimization
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ViewEngine());

        var settingService = Engine.Resolve<ISettingService>();
        //Start system task
        if (settingService.GetSetting("system.task.enable").BoolValue)
        {
            TaskManager.Instance.Initialize();
            TaskManager.Instance.Start();
        }

        //Set system setting
        AntiForgeryConfig.RequireSsl = settingService.GetSetting("system.usessl").BoolValue;
        SecurityHelper.EncryptKey = settingService.GetSetting("system.default.encryptionkey").Value;

        //Initialize Notification
        if (settingService.GetSetting("system.manage.notification").BoolValue)
            InitializeNotification();

        Singleton<IMetaBuilder>.Instance = new MetaBuilder();
    }

    private void InitializeNotification()
    {
        /*string connectionString = WebHelper.ConnectionString("connectionString");
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        NotifyEngine engine = new NotifyEngine(connectionString);
        string query = "select Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 from [dbo].Test";
        engine.OnNotifyChange += delegate (SqlNotificationInfo info)
        {
            var testService = Engine.Resolve<ITestService>();
            NotificationHub.showNotify(testService.GetLast().ToJsonString());
        };
        engine.RegisterSqlDependency(query, SqlNotificationInfo.Update, SqlNotificationInfo.Insert);*/
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        InitializeApplication();
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(WebHelper.ConnectionString("connectionString"));
    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Request is Search Engine(GoogleBot, MsnBot vs.)
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Crawler)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://google.com", true);
            return;
        }

        if (CookieHelper.Exists(SessionConstant.Location))
        {
            var country = CookieHelper.Get(SessionConstant.Location).FromBase64().FromJsonString<Country>();
            WebHelper.SetCulture(country);
        }
        else
        {
            var location = Engine.Resolve<IHelperService>().FindLocation(WebHelper.IsLocal, WebHelper.IpAddress);
            var country = Engine.Resolve<ICommonService>().GetCountryByCode(location.CountryCode);
            WebHelper.SetCulture(country);
            CookieHelper.Set(SessionConstant.Location, country.ToJsonString().ToBase64(), 1);
        }
    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebHelper.ClearSession();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WebHelper.IsStaticResource(this.Request))
            return;

        var settingService = Engine.Resolve<ISettingService>();

        if (settingService.GetSetting("system.usessl").BoolValue &&
            !WebHelper.IsSecureConnection &&
            WebHelper.GetUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
        {
            //Redirect to https
            var scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps + "://";
            var authority = WebHelper.GetUri.Authority;
            var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

            var redirectTo = scheme + authority + url;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectTo);
        }
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WebHelper.IsLocal)
            return;

        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        bool isAjaxRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper(this.Request).IsAjaxRequest();
        if (!WebHelper.IsStaticResource(Request) && !isAjaxRequest && exception != null)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            //Log Error
            var error = new SystemError()
            {
                RestaurantId = WebHelper.CurrentRestaurant.Id,
                ErrorDate = DateTime.Now,
                ErrorType = ErrorType.Warning,
                ErrorMessage = exception.ToString(),
                ErrorLocation = WebHelper.GetCurrentUrl(true),
                ErrorStack = exception.StackTrace.ToString()
            };
            var logService = Engine.Resolve<ILogService>();
            logService.Error(error);
            Context.Response.Redirect("/error", true);
        }
    }
```

Views/web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <!--<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">-->
    <pages pageBaseType="Restaurant.Framework.Infrastructure.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <clear />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Restaurant.Manage" />
        <add namespace="Restaurant.Manage.Models" />
        <add namespace="Restaurant.Framework" />
        <add namespace="Restaurant.Framework.Paging" />
        <add namespace="Restaurant.Framework.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="Restaurant.Core.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="Restaurant.Core.Enums" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Error",
                 url: "Error",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "NotFound",
                 url: "NotFound",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "AccessDenied",
                 url: "AccessDenied",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "SiteNotAvailable",
                 url: "SiteNotAvailable",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "SiteNotAvailable" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Notification",
                 url: "Notification",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Notification" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Support",
                 url: "Support",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Support" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "About",
                 url: "About",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Contact",
                 url: "Contact",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Restaurant.Manage.Controllers" });
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: what about if you try to access a specific view which you know exists? Without seeing the code it's hard to know if you've done something wrong.

Comment: Instead of using a web brower, use telnet to see what the server is actually sending. Failing that, "View source" in the browser combined with the Dev tools is nearly as good

Comment: can you show the routing config code?

Comment: I have no problem before. 
I started living after removed the glimpse plugin from the project.

Comment: "I started living after removed the glimpse plugin from the project". This sentence does not make sense. Can you clarify?